# Bind ajax request to specific element Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a list of users who each have a 'follow' button next to their name. The 'follow' request is complete via ajax and the follow button then changes to a 'unfollow' button.

My code works fine with one user listed (and also works back-end with multiple users listed)  but what I would like is to list multiple users and then somehow bind the follow request to the specific element, '.follow_form' which each button is contained in, so that only the one child 'follow' button which is clicked changes to the 'unfollow'.

The jquery code which I'm having trouble binding is as follows:

```
    /create.js.erb

    $(".follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
```

and

```
    /destroy.js.erb

    $(".follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
```

When the form is submitted obviously all the .follow_form element are changed  but I can't work out how to bind the correct element?

One of a few pieces of code I tried (for create.js.erb) was:

```
    $("input.follow").bind( function() {
      $(this).closest(".follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
    });
```

But no response???

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be doing this in an `ajax:success` callback instead since it is automatically bound to the object.

You can delete those `.js.erb` files and just render them in the controller:

```
def create
  # creation code here

  # now render the response
  render :json => { :new_button => render_to_string( :partial => 'users/unfollow' ) },
         :status => :created
end

def destroy
  # deletion code here

  # now render the response
  render :json => { :new_button => render_to_string( :partial => 'users/follow' ) },
         :status => :no_content
end
```

Then in your javascript file:

```
$('input.follow, input.unfollow').live('ajax:success', function(data, json, response) {
  $(this).closest(".follow_form").html(json.new_button);
});
$('input.follow, input.unfollow').live('ajax:error', function(data, xhr, response) {
  // handle the ajax error here
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but your code doesnt seem to be working? The button just stays the same until I refresh the page.

Comment: You probably don't have jQuery installed correctly or double-check that a `.follow-form` element exists on the page.  To make sure it's installed correctly: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs#readme

Comment: I definitely have it installed correctly,rail 3.1 plus I have many other jquery functions working correctly, and yes .follow_form exists.

Comment: Open up your browser console and type this: `$('input.follow, input.unfollow').closest(".follow_form").html("This should change something.");`... If that doesn't work, then you may want to check the dom structure to make sure `closest` is finding `follow_form` correctly